# how to freely draw / doodle a line on an Image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

i have searched the solution for this case, but i didn't find it on the internet. i want to draw/doodle a line like snapchat or whatsapp status that allow user to draw freely. I found a similar tutorial  but it just drew on the UIView in this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbFHqHHApC4&t=7s

[image]

i want to allow user to freely draw on the image they pick from image gallery/camera, and then save the result back as the UIImage

[image]

the source code of the doodle on the UIView (the first picture) is below

first, make the custom view

```
class DrawView : ShadowView {

    var isDrawing = false
    var lastPoint : CGPoint!
    var strokeColor : CGColor! = UIColor.black.cgColor
    var strokes = [Stroke]()


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        guard !isDrawing else { return }
        isDrawing = true

        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        lastPoint = currentPoint
        print(currentPoint)


    }



    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


        guard isDrawing else { return}

        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        let stroke = Stroke(startPoint: lastPoint, endPoint: currentPoint, strokeColor: strokeColor)
        strokes.append(stroke)
        lastPoint = currentPoint

        setNeedsDisplay()


        print(currentPoint)
    }




    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

         guard isDrawing else { return}
         isDrawing = false 

        guard let touch = touches.first else {return}

        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
        let stroke = Stroke(startPoint: lastPoint, endPoint: currentPoint, strokeColor: strokeColor)
        strokes.append(stroke)

        setNeedsDisplay() 

        lastPoint = nil
        print(currentPoint)

    }


    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setLineWidth(5) 
        context?.setLineCap(.round) 

        for stroke in strokes {
            context?.beginPath()

            context?.move(to: stroke.startPoint)
            context?.addLine(to: stroke.endPoint)

            context?.setStrokeColor(stroke.strokeColor)
            context?.strokePath()
        }

    }


    func erase() {
        strokes = []
        strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        setNeedsDisplay() // ditampilkan ke layar
    }



}
```

The struct of the stoke is like this one :

```
struct  Stroke {
    let startPoint : CGPoint
    let endPoint : CGPoint
    let strokeColor : CGColor

}
```

after that, assign the custom view to ViewController :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var drawView: DrawView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }



    @IBAction func yellowDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        drawView.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    }


    @IBAction func redDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
         drawView.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

    @IBAction func blueDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
         drawView.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    }

    @IBAction func erasedDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        drawView.erase()
    }

}
```

so how if i want to apply that custom view on the UIImageView and save the result as the new UIImage? I am new in programming actually, really needyour help. Thanks :)

Comment: Same question, any resolution to this?